# Given two numbers a and b , find Nth number which is divisible by a or b.

Tags: divisibility

Input:
a=2
b=3
N=10

The numbers which are divisible by 
2 or 3 are: 2,3,4,6,8,9,10,12,14,15 and the 10th number is 15.

Comment: I don't suppose there is a simple closed formula for this.  It's easy enough to search though...for any bound $M$ list all the multiples of $a,b$ which are $≤M$ and then sort.

Answer (score 2):

This question is regarding an online coding competition. Any one who wants to answer this please wait till 1:00 AM, 11 September, 2017 Indian Standard Time.

Link : https://www.hackerearth.com/challenge/hiring/amazon-developer-hiring-challenge

Comment: Aren't we past Aug 11 2017? Or did you mean September? And what competition is it?

Comment: If this is from a live coding competition please supply a link to the competition so the question can be closed.

Comment: https://www.hackerearth.com/challenge/hiring/amazon-developer-hiring-challenge/